# Graphical glitches in chromium-based apps

Tags: graphics, chromium, atom

Since yesterday I have been experiencing annoying graphical glitches in all chromium based applications - atom, popcorn-time and chrome itself. Here are the screenshots:

atom:

[image: screen tear?]

popcorn-time:

[image: window fragments]

How can I get rid of them?

Comment: Problem might be in chromium .... but did you try changing the video card driver in "additional drivers"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turned out that problem solves by restarting computer. Thanks anyway guys.